# Wave function symmetry on Fock space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, wavefunction

Let's consider two electrons, created in the following manner

$c^{\dagger}_{k_1,u} c^{\dagger}_{k_2,d} |0\rangle$,

where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the wavenumbers, and $u$ and $d$ stand for up and down spin directions, respectively.

My first question is what kind of symmetry the wave function has in this state. It is known that spins $u$ and $d$ together can form singlet or triplet states. Hence, there are two possibilities. Does it need to be symmetrized? If there are many electrons, the situation gets more complicated. For $N$ number of electrons there are $2^N$ spin variations. How to symmetrize the wavefunction then?

Comment: Just anti-symmetric for each electron.

Comment: Can you exchange $k_1$, $k_2$ separately from $u$ and $d$?